# Segmentation Fault in C command line arguments while trying to add to array

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault, command-line-arguments, cs50

I'm new to C and this programme is supposed to output `usage: ./substitution key` when the user enters a key that is not alphabetic. In the case that the key is less than 27 letters long, it should output a message that the key must be 26 letters long. The first error message is generated if no input is given by the user. Giving no input is working, and printing the valid error message.  However, if I try giving other inputs, i.e, adding characters to the array, it shows segmentation fault. Can you please help me out?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[argc])
{
    int counter = 0;
    if (argc==1)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
    }
    for (int i = 1;i <= argc; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(argv[i]) != 0)
            continue;
        else
            counter++;
    }
    if (counter>1)
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
    else if (argc!=27 && argc!=1)
        printf("key must contain 26 characters.\n");
}
```

Comment: `argv` is an array of strings, not chars. `isalpha(argv[i])` is invalid.

Comment: `char*argv[argc]` should be `char*argv[]`

Comment: thank you! I'll change that

Answer (score 1):

You are going out of array boundaries. Change this:

```
for (int i = 1 ;i <= argc; i++)
```

to this

```
for (int i = 1 ;i < argc; i++)
```

And you misuse argv - it is an array of null-terminated strings. The size of the array is argc, the length of each string can be obtained with strlen function. Check the following code for example.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 1) {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
    }

    const char *key = argv[1]; // for convenience
    int counter = 0;
    // count alphas
    while (isalpha(key[counter])) { ++counter; }
    // count length
    int len = strlen(key);

    // check if key consists of alphas
    if (counter != len) {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
    }
    // check length
    if (counter != 26) {
        printf("key must contain 26 characters.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's acutally no out of bounds access. `argv[argc]` is valid and should contain a `NULL` pointer to terminate the list of arguments. But of course the loop should stop one element earlier or there should be a check for `NULL`

Comment: The question is only marked as C. You might update your code to be valid C, not C++.